# Null value when I trying to inject bean to servlet filter via spring

Tags: java, spring, filter

My web.xml:

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!--Listeners-->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!--Params-->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:*-applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="studentModel" class="ru.spb.herzen.jviewer.model.StudentModel" scope="session">
   <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFilter" class="ru.spb.herzen.jviewer.filter.SessionFilter" init-method="init">
   <property name="userModel" ref="studentModel"/>
</bean>

<bean id="roleFilter" class="ru.spb.herzen.jviewer.filter.RoleFilter">
   <property name="userModel" ref="studentModel"/>
</bean>

<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
   <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="
            sessionFilter,
            roleFilter"/>
   </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>
```

When I try to login, the filter fails. In debug, I saw that value of userModel is null. I also tried to add filters separately, but result is same. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I dont know if this is possible but a shot in the dark... Maybe because your not logged in yet the studentModel is not created due to its "session" scope

Comment: @ns47731 yes, but I wait, that filter works only when I logged in. How I can to this?

Comment: @ns47731 Method, in which I get user data, invoking before filter, but in filter user data is empty. 
Before: LoginController - data is good. After: filter - data is empty.